# Hiding/Showing Div Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

This should cycle through the `<div>` tags, but it isn't even showing the first one. It should show a "0", then 50ms later, show "1", then "2", and then "3". I get nothing.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="header" id="animation">
<div id="aniObj0" style="display: none;" onLoad="runAnimation();">0</div>
<div id="aniObj1" style="display: none;">1</div>
<div id="aniObj2" style="display: none;">2</div>
<div id="aniObj3" style="display: none;">3</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var aniNum = 0;
var animationDelay = 50;
var frameDelay = 50;

function runAnimation()
{
    Console.log("runningAnimation");
    var prevObj = document.getElementById('aniObj' + (aniNum - 1));
    var aniObj = document.getElementById('aniObj' + aniNum);
    if(aniObj != null){
        if(prevObj != null){
            aniObj.style.display = 'none;';
        }
        aniObj.style.display = 'block;';
        aniNum++;
        if(aniNum == 0){
            setTimeout("runAnimation();", animationDelay);
        }else{
            setTimeout("runAnimation();", frameDelay);
        }
    }else{
        aniNum = 0;
        newAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: try with "aniObj.style.display = '';"

Comment: :o <div onload=""> does no exist, you need <body onload="runAnimation();">, then will be sufficient setTimeout(runAnimation, animationDelay); instead of "runAnimation();"

Comment: Is there a browser in which `Console.log` won't cause a reference error? In all the browsers I have tested it is `console` with no capital "c". Unless, of course, `Console` is user-defined.

Comment: Are you still having an issue? Have either of the answers been helpful?

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. See code below (and comments in code).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header" id="animation">
    <!-- Removed onload="runAnimation()" - onload doesn't exist for a div -->
    <div id="aniObj0" style="display: none;">0</div>
    <div id="aniObj1" style="display: none;">1</div>
    <div id="aniObj2" style="display: none;">2</div>
    <div id="aniObj3" style="display: none;">3</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var aniNum = 0;
var animationDelay = 500; //Changed to 500ms to you could see better
var frameDelay = 500; //Changed to 500ms to you could see better

function runAnimation()
{
    var prevObj = document.getElementById('aniObj' + (aniNum - 1));
    var aniObj = document.getElementById('aniObj' + aniNum);

    if (aniObj != null) {
        if (prevObj != null) {
            aniObj.style.display = 'none;';
        }
        aniObj.style.display = '';
        aniNum++;
        if (aniNum == 0) {
            //Changed setTimeout("runAnimation()", animationDelay); to 
            //setTimeout(runAnimation, animationDelay);
            setTimeout(runAnimation, animationDelay);
        } else {
            setTimeout(runAnimation, frameDelay);
        }
    } else {
        aniNum = 0;
        newAnimation();
    }
}

//You need to place this in a valid event. onload event of the body maybe?
runAnimation();
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeL8A/).